# PHPExcel Auto Date Format for excel

Tags: php, phpexcel, date-formatting

I'm using PHPExcel to create Excel files and I have some "Date" columns which keeps the date values. However, PHPExcel forces me to define a date format to work with the date fields. For example

```
const FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2             = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
const FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD              = 'yy-mm-dd';
const FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY              = 'dd/mm/yy';
const FORMAT_DATE_DMYSLASH              = 'd/m/y';
const FORMAT_DATE_DMYMINUS              = 'd-m-y';
const FORMAT_DATE_DMMINUS               = 'd-m';
const FORMAT_DATE_MYMINUS               = 'm-y';
const FORMAT_DATE_XLSX14                = 'mm-dd-yy';
const FORMAT_DATE_XLSX15                = 'd-mmm-yy';
const FORMAT_DATE_XLSX16                = 'd-mmm';
```

However, this is limited since you have to use one of these formats. What I want is, giving the date to PHPExcel without formatting (or with some special formatting type) and Excel would show it according to users current locale. If I use one of this formats the guy lives in USA would read a different time format to which he is not familiar to or the same situation for users who lives in different countries. In short, somehow excel must show the date in current locale of the user. Is this possible somehow? I googled but no chance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> However, this is limited since you
>   have to use one of these formats.

You aren't restricted to using the constants. In the same way as you can define custom format masks for dates in MS Excel itself, you can do so in PHPExcel as well. You just have to define the masking sting yourself.

> What I want is, giving the date to
>   PHPExcel without formatting (or with
>   some special formatting type) and
>   Excel would show it according to users
>   current locale. If I use one of this
>   formats the guy lives in USA would
>   read a different time format to which
>   he is not familiar to or the same
>   situation for users who lives in
>   different countries.

But you can't automatically change that date format mask when a file is viewed in MS Excel based on the MS Excel locale.

> In short, somehow excel must show the
>   date in current locale of the user. Is
>   this possible somehow?

Does MS Excel give you this option? If so, how would you do it in MS Excel? I don't know every single feature of Excel, so it may be possible; but I'm not aware of how you would do it.